# Leaflet remove current marker and add a new one on click

Tags: django, routes, leaflet, coordinates, gis

I'm currently routing to a marker, but I want to be able to choose another route and the current marker will then be rerouted.

Image one shows the current routing.

On click of the 'Route to here' button the current marker must be removed and replaced with the new marker.

[Image current routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRgYt.png)

[OnClick this should remove the current marker and add a new marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHLKy.png)

```
function showPosition(position) 
    {

    //Set the map view to be the users location
    //

    var map = L.map('map').setView([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude], 14);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    //Change the users marker to a unique red & show users location on click
    //

    L.marker([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude], {
        icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({prefix: 'fa', markerColor: 'red'})
    }).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>Your location: </b>" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude);

    //Routing users location to the desired route
    //

    L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [L.latLng(users_lat_coords, users_lng_coords), L.latLng(x, y)],
                lineOptions: {addWaypoints: false}
        }
    ).addTo(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer of the leaflet routing machine library is still working on the code to achieve this, so a workaround was done. If a route has previously been made, I splice the waypoint and add a new one in.

```
var routing ='';
var been_routed=false;
function route_to_station(point_lat_coords, point_lng_coords, x1, y1) {
                users_lat_coords = point_lat_coords;
                users_lng_coords = point_lng_coords;
                x = x1;
                y = y1;

                if (x !== '') {
                    if (been_routed === true) {
                        routing.spliceWaypoints(0, 1);
                    }
                    routing = L.Routing.control({
                            waypoints: [L.latLng(users_lat_coords, users_lng_coords), L.latLng(x, y)],
                            lineOptions: {addWaypoints: false}

                        }
                    );
                    routing.addTo(map);
                    been_routed = true;

                }
            }
```